# How do I know when a process has been killed

Tags: process, kill, htop

The following code starts a lenghty nmap process and then the main program tries to kill it. I am running it from shell and also have GTOP running in another window just to see if all is successfull.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
int ret,childpid=0;
ret = fork();
if (ret == 0)
   {
   printf("Here A %d.. \n", ret);
   char *params[5]  = {"nmap","-sS","-A","192.168.0.1/24",0}; //cmd params filled
   childpid = execv( "/usr/bin/nmap" , params);  //parameters for cmd
   printf("\n child exiting (%d) (%d).. \n", childpid,errno); //on successful execution of cmd, this exit never appears
   }
else
   {
   childpid=ret;  
   printf("parent exiting\n");
   if (childpid!=0)
      { 
      printf("child %d about to be killed wait 15 so that htop has time to see it\n",childpid);
      sleep(15);
      kill(childpid, SIGTERM);  
      sleep(2);
      kill(childpid, SIGKILL);
      printf("killed wait 15 HTOP should have time to update\n");
      sleep(15);
      }
   }
return 1;
}
```

HTOP see nmap starting but when I kill the process it still shows in the HTOP display. When my main program exit HTOP removes nmap from list of processes. Am I doing something wrong or misinterpreting HTOP?

Answer (score 3):

You spawned a child process, killed it, and didn't `wait(2)` for it. The process is now a zombie, hanging around for its parent. When the parent process dies, the zombie becomes an orphan, and init takes care of it. From [`man 2 wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) on Linux:

> In the case of a terminated child, performing a    wait allows the
>   system to release the resources associated with the    child; if a
>   wait is not performed, then the terminated child remains    in a
>   "zombie" state (see NOTES below).

And from the notes:

> A child that terminates, but has not been waited for becomes a 
>   "zombie". The kernel maintains a minimal set of information about 
>   the zombie process (PID, termination status, resource usage 
>   information) in order to allow the parent to later perform a wait to 
>   obtain information about the child.  As long as a zombie is not 
>   removed from the system via a wait, it will consume a slot in the 
>   kernel process table, and if this table fills, it will not be 
>   possible to create further processes.  If a parent process 
>   terminates, then its "zombie" children (if any) are adopted by 
>   init(1), (or by the nearest "subreaper" process as defined through 
>   the use of the prctl(2) PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER operation); init(1) 
>   automatically performs a wait to remove the zombies.

So, `wait()` for the child process, or it will hang around until the parent process dies.

Comment: My example in my original post been cut down from larger program. Eventually I plan to do the following:

Comment: 1) from my main program launch a process (here for example nmap)
2) while nmap is running I do some other stuff in my main program.
3) later I check is the process (nmap) still running. If too much time has passed I just kill the process (nmap)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. If I change the kill -part as follows:

```
      ...
      { 
      printf("child %d about to be killed wait 15 so that htop has time to see it\n",childpid);
      sleep(15);
      kill(childpid, SIGKILL);  
      waitpid(childpid,&ret,WUNTRACED);
      }
   }
return 1;
}
```

Adding that waitpid seems to clear the process from HTOP. If someone knows any caveat (why should I use SIGKILL instead of SIGTERM or should I use something else than WUNTRACED?) please let mr know.